# Proving an identity with geometric series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, summation, power-series

I've been at this for MANY hours and I think it's time I sought help.

> Question: Given $k = \frac{2 \pi}{Na}\left ( p-\frac{N}{2} \right )$, prove that $\sum_{k=1}^{N}e^{ika\left ( n-m \right )}=N\delta_{mn}$

Hint:
$\sum_{p=1}^{N}=\frac{x\left ( x^{N}-1 \right )}{x-1}$ for x $\in \mathbb{C}$ and $x \neq 1$

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The hint is not written down properly, what should it say? And also, what is $\delta_{mn}$? Actually, can you explain all symbols involved? What are they? Random numbers? Do they satisfy something?

Comment: The symbol in your reply is a kronecker delta. 
m,n and N are all natural numbers. a is some constant.

Comment: I think we can prove it with exponential Fourier-series relations , and [Fourier analysis](http://www.people.fas.harvard.edu/~djmorin/waves/Fourier.pdf) I hope it can help you